# Logout and login_check symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm following documentation about authentication

> Logging Out
>   Usually, you'll also want your users to be able to log
>   out. Fortunately, the firewall can handle this automatically for you
>   when you activate the logout config parameter:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            # ...
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
    # ...
```

Same thing for login_check.
Where is login_check or logout in Symfony ? these route are "globally"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> these route are "globally"?

Yes, You can see this functionality in namespace:

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider
```

and

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout
```

Of course it isn't impossible, you can write you own login & logout action.

For example I wrote my logout action like in example:

```
class LogoutController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->get('security.context')->setToken(NULL);
        return $this->redirect(
            $this->generateUrl('homepage')
        );
    }
}
```

Take a look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html).